# First and second fragment showing same data

Tags: android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have 6 fragments, all with the same layout and functionality, the data [A,B,C,D,...] for each fragment is different. When the first two fragments are created I view B,B then C then D...etc. Swiping back from C I get the correct data viewed C, B, A.
I can't see what I am doing wrong. Here is a bit of code :

```
private class ScreenSlidePagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    private final Bundle fragmentBundle;

    public ScreenSlidePagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, Bundle data) {
        super(fm);
        fragmentBundle = data;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // creating fragment and passing int position for array and array
        return SoundFrag.newInstance(position, fragmentBundle);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NUM_PAGES;
    }
}
```

and the fragment class :

```
public class SoundFrag extends Fragment{
    // fragment Id Postion
    private int fragPosition;
    private static final String KEY_POSITION="fragIntIdP";

    static SoundFrag newInstance(int position, Bundle arrayIntS) {
        SoundFrag frag=new SoundFrag();
        arrayIntS.putInt(KEY_POSITION, position);
        frag.setArguments(arrayIntS);

        return(frag);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // retrive data from bundle passed by activity
        Bundle argsIn = getArguments();
        SoundArrayParcel arrayToReceive = argsIn.getParcelable("dataResId");
        final int[][] arrayResId = arrayToReceive.getInt();
        fragPosition = argsIn.getInt("fragIntIdP");

        // inflate the fragment
        final ViewGroup rootView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.sounds_frag, container, false);
```

.....
I believe the problem to be here. The value of fragPosition is always 1 for the first two fragments, instead of 0 and then 1. Why?

Thanks for any help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what it's worth...

I changed the code so that the array was no longer passed to the fragment via Bundle. I now only pass the position value of the fragment (from the `getItem(int position)` method) and the array is 'constructed' within the fragment once it inflates.
The condition I was noticing before (`fragposition` being 1 for both first and second fragments) no longer happens and the apps displays the information correctly.
Why ? Not sure, but it works. I will however continue to investigate as I don't like the solution I found.